# Changing an array of objects scales over time and then deleating them one after the other

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

At the moment, I create a list of objects depending if any children are found in a range of objects. This list should then be passed to a Function, which should go through this list, shrink each tile, and delete them one by one.

So far this is my code:

```
    void OnMouseUp(){
    subobj = new GameObject[transform.childCount];
    RaycastHit hit;
    hitCheck = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < transform.childCount; i++) {
        subobj [i] = transform.GetChild (i).gameObject;
    }//store sub objects in array

    foreach (GameObject child in subobj){
        if (Physics.Raycast (child.transform.position, Vector3.down, out hit)) {
            if (hit.collider.tag != "Tile")
                hitCheck = false;
        } else {
            hitCheck = false;
        }
        // if any one of the sub objects doesnt hit a tile then return to original position
    }

    if (hitCheck) {
        foreach (GameObject child in subobj) {
            Physics.Raycast (child.transform.position, Vector3.down, out hit);
            child.transform.position = hit.transform.position;
            child.transform.parent = hit.transform;
            // if a object hit something, child each sub object to what it hit

            GameObject.Find("Spawns").GetComponent<CreatingItems>().score += 1f;
        }
        transform.parent = null;
        GameObject.Destroy (this.gameObject);
        // destroy the old parent container
    } else {
        transform.position = startPoint;
        transform.localScale = originalScale;
        // return to original position
    }

    if (GameObject.Find ("Spawn1").transform.childCount == 0 && GameObject.Find ("Spawn2").transform.childCount == 0 && GameObject.Find ("Spawn3").transform.childCount == 0) {
        CreatingItems ci = GameObject.Find ("Spawns").GetComponent<CreatingItems> ();
        ci.Spawn ();
    }// if spawn position is empty spawn new items

    tileList = new GameObject[GameObject.Find ("Generated Map").transform.childCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < GameObject.Find ("Generated Map").transform.childCount; i++) {
        tileList [i] = GameObject.Find ("Generated Map").transform.GetChild (i).gameObject;
    }// stores all tiles as gameobjects in a list.

    destroyList.Clear (); // clears the list of items to be destroyed

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        ChildCheckY = true;
        ChildCheckX = true;

        for (int y = 0; y <= 9; y++) {
            if (tileList [(i*10) + y].transform.childCount == 0) {
                ChildCheckY = false;
                // checks if y values has children, if no child is found false is returned
            }
        }
        for (int x = 0; x <= 9; x++) {
            if (tileList[i + (10*x)].transform.childCount == 0) {
                ChildCheckX = false;
                // checks if x values has children, if no child is found false is returned
            }
        }
        if (ChildCheckY) {
            for (int y = 0; y <= 9; y++) {
                destroyList.Add(tileList [(i * 10) + y].transform.GetChild (0).gameObject);
                //Scale (tileList [(i * 10) + y].transform.GetChild (0).gameObject);
                // destroys 10 y values in a row
            }
        }
        if (ChildCheckX) {
            for (int x = 0; x <= 9; x++) {
                destroyList.Add(tileList [i + (10 * x)].transform.GetChild (0).gameObject);
                //Scale (tileList [i + (10 * x)].transform.GetChild (0).gameObject);
                // destroys 10 x values in a row
            }
        }
    }
    if(destroyList.Count>=10)
        StartCoroutine (Scale (destroyList));
}

IEnumerator Scale(List<GameObject> listdestroy){
    CreatingItems speed = GameObject.Find ("Spawns").GetComponent<CreatingItems> ();
    foreach(GameObject gameobj in listdestroy){
        while (gameobj.transform.localScale.x > 0.2f){
            gameobj.transform.localScale -= new Vector3 (0.1f, 0.05f, 0.1f) * Time.deltaTime * speed.deletespeed;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.1f);
        }
    }
    yield return null;
}
```

the first object in the delete list gets reduced by 0.04, and the coroutine "Scale" exits after that and wont scale the rest of the items, when i change the code all the items scale within 1 frame rather than over time. 
this is my full code

Comment: You want a value that it changes by each second, say `10`. Then each time you update check `Time.deltaTime` and multiply your value by it, this will uniformly change the size of the object at a steady rate. For example if the time between frames is 0.2 seconds (god forbid), it would increase size by 2. If the time between frames was (more realistically) 0.02 seconds, it would increase by 0.2

Answer (score 0):

Your code :

```
IEnumerator destroyer(){
    CreatingItems speed = GameObject.Find ("Spawns").GetComponent<CreatingItems> ();
    for (int i = 0; i < destroyList.Count; i++) {
        do {
            destroyList [i].transform.localScale = Vector3.MoveTowards(destroyList[i].transform.localScale, Vector3.zero,Time.deltaTime*speed.deletespeed);
        } while (destroyList [i].transform.localScale.x > 0.1f);
        Destroy (destroyList [i].gameObject);
    }
    yield return null;
}
```

Is deleting all objects ASAP. You should use some delay inside loop like :

```
IEnumerator destroyer(){
    CreatingItems speed = GameObject.Find ("Spawns").GetComponent<CreatingItems> ();
    for (int i = 0; i < destroyList.Count; i++) {
        do {
            destroyList [i].transform.localScale = Vector3.MoveTowards(destroyList[i].transform.localScale, Vector3.zero,Time.deltaTime*speed.deletespeed);
            yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame(); // < == HERE! wait for end frame
        } while (destroyList [i].transform.localScale.x > 0.1f);
        Destroy (destroyList [i].gameObject);
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame(); // < == HERE! wait for end frame
    }
    yield return null;
}
```

Comment: that almost worked, now the first object shrinks partially and stops, im guessing when the endofframe is called it exits the co routine

Comment: Coroutine will end with the last `yield return ...` statement.

Comment: then why isnt the object being destroyed ?

Comment: I think it's because it's scale never goes below `0.1f` and it loops constantly.

Comment: i can get it to delete all the objects, they arent scaling over time. they instantly scale to > 0.1f and then delete without scaling over time

Answer (score 0):

i figured out a solution, i essentially wasnt allowing the coroutine to complete before moving onto the next object as i was calling it only once inside of OnMouseUp, therefore i changed the code to the following to fix it

```
void Update(){
        StartCoroutine (Scale());
    }
...
IEnumerator Scale(){
    CreatingItems speed = GameObject.Find ("Spawns").GetComponent<CreatingItems> ();
    foreach (GameObject gameobj in destroyList) {
        yield return null;
        while (Vector3.Distance (gameobj.transform.localScale, new Vector3 (0.1f, 0.05f, 0.1f)) > 0.1f) {
            gameobj.transform.localScale -= new Vector3 (0.1f, 0.05f, 0.1f) * Time.deltaTime * speed.deletespeed;
            yield return null;
        }
        Destroy (gameobj);
    }
}
```